# regex in sublime to select tags

Tags: html, regex, sublimetext, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I wanted to select lines which has below pattern though RegEx.

```
<div><span class="ft0">DESCRIPTION</span></div>
<div><img width="850" height="1100" src="some random names.jpg" ALT=""></div>
```

Here I wanted to find lines which has class names `"ft0"` and 
lines which has `img` tags in it.

I am using sublime to find and replace all these occurrences from folder.

I have tried the following to replace all occurrences:

```
<div><span class="ft1">(.+)</span></div> and <div> <img (.+)></div>
```

Comment: I used <div><span class="ft1">(.+)</span></div> and <div>
<img (.+)></div> to replace all occurance

Comment: He included his attempt as a comment.  I moved it into the main question.

Answer (score 1):

I take it you want to match the entire line if it meets the conditions.

How about this:

```
.*(?:<[^<>]*class="ft0"|<img).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/vL8mL8/1

If you want to be more specific about only matching between tags, you could do something like:

```
(?:<[^<>]+>)*(?:<[^<>]*class="ft0"|<img)(?:.*?<\/[^<>]+>)*
```

https://regex101.com/r/nA1nT7/1

Answer (score 0):

May be you can try this : `(?:^.*class="ft0".*|^.*<img .*)`

> ?:--> checks for the OR condition. In first condition " class="ft0" is
>   checked for. In second condition "
>
> Here it checks for the presence of either of the condition. and if any
>   of the condition satisfies, it shows you the full line.
>   You can fetch the captured lines with the help of numbered groups.

PS: Do not forget to escape the characters.